# Error in kendo grid - grid.select is not a function why?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendoDropDown list as a cell in my grid. I am calling the kendDropDownList using the editor command of kendo grid ("editor"). I need to pass selected value of selected row to kendoDropDownList as a parameter in order to server reply back only with filtered list as my kendoDropDownList . Please see my below example

```
                         var grid =  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    pageable: true,
                    columnMenu:true,
                    filterable:true,
                    height: 550,
                    reorderable: true,
            columnReorder: function(e) {
                        console.log(e.column.field, e.newIndex, e.oldIndex);
                      },
                    toolbar: ["create","excel","save", "cancel" , { template: kendo.template($("#template").html()) } , { template: kendo.template($("#clearFilterTemplate").html()) } , { name: "create", text: "Add New Employee" }],
                    excel: {
                            fileName: "Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx",
                            proxyURL: "excelExport",
                            filterable: true,
                            allPages: true
                        },                        
                     editable: "inline" , //editable: true,
                     columns: [
                                { field: "fileNo" , title:"File No" , width: 80 },
                                { field: "jobNo" , title:"Job No" , width: 80 },
                                { field: "discipline" , title:"Discipline" , width: 80 },
                                { field: "moduleNo" ,title:"Module", width: 100},
                                { field: "description",title:"Title",editor: descriptionDropDownEditor, width: 150},
                                { field: "documentNo",title:"Document No", width: 150 },
                                { field: "remarks",title:"Remarks" , width: 150 } ,
                                { command: ["edit","destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }

                            ]


                });


                function descriptionDropDownEditor(container, options) {

                 // here is the error grid.select is not a function why ?
                 var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
                 var selectedJobNo = selectedItem.jobNo ;
                 alert("selectedJobNo :"+selectedJobNo  );


                $('<input required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoDropDownList({
                        autoBind: false,
                        dataTextField: "text",
                        dataValueField: "value",
                        filter: "contains",
                        dataSource: {
                            dataType: "json",                                 
                            transport: {
                                // I need to pass the selected jobNo in order to get the only aprropriate descrption for that jobNo
                                // each row job has description and I don't want to show all the description for all jobs , I need only for that row jobNo

                                 read: "getDescriptionForEachDocumentIndex?selectedJobNo"+selectedJobNo 
                            }
                        }
                          });
                }
```

once the row of grid in edit mode I need to pass the selected row jobNo to kendoDropDownList in order to respond back with only releated description for that jobNo. The problem is i can not call grid in the edit mode and use the function grid.select() . what to do in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that is easy. The second parameter of your editor function has a property called *model*, which is the dataItem of the current row user is editing. So in your case, I supose this would work:

```
function descriptionDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    var selectedItem = options.model;
```

But, to answer your question, you can't access the `select()` method because `grid` is not a Kendo Grid object, it is in fact the `#grid` element. You can either add `.data("kendoGrid")` at the end of the widget initialization:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({ ... }).data("kendoGrid");
```

Or call it inside the function:

```
function descriptionDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    var gridWidget = $(grid).data("kendoGrid");
    var selectedItem = gridWidget.dataItem(gridWidget.select());
```

Comment: thanks DontVoteMeDown , you have answered my question with  I have two small questions

Comment: @AliAlawi first of all, please dont post answers with more questions, that is not right. Post comments in my answers instead. Well, I don't know why you still get the error, because what I suggested is in the documentation. You dont have two elements with `id=grid`, dont you? About the `options.model` I've found it out by myself. When I come across an event of a widget that I dont really know, I just use `console.log(arguments)` inside the event to see what it gives to me.